# jQuery Mobile page fixed footer blocks page content after dynamically changing its content

Tags: jquery-mobile

1. the origin html is a jqm page with an fixed empty footer
2. after the jqm page loaded, using ajax to retrieve some data and put it in the footer
3. the footer's  height expands and blocks some area of the page content, which originally would show just above the footer

What should I do to avoid this blocking?

[The blocking illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz7G2.png)

Comment: what do you mean by blocking?? post a screenshot

Comment: the 2nd image is the blocking one with the larger footer??

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou yes, as the content within the fixed footer was changed dynamically, and the new content expanded the footer height.

Comment: Yes, so it will expand if you keep adding html data to it. I gave you a solution the other day not to do that by using CSS -- .ui-footer-fixed {
  max-height: 43px;
}  -- but you said it didnt work. That's the only way i know to keep the footer from expanding -- another way is to give the footer a lower z-index value from the main content so its behind it -- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou Thank you for that answer, but my description may cause some misunderstanding, what I wanted was not to keep the fixed footer from expanding.

So here was the thing, after the footer expanded, when I scrolled down the page to the bottom, the last few content was blocked.

I 'solved' this problem by stuffing some fake data, which made the fixed footer height expanded beforehand. I posted the question to seek some decent solutions.